# Use echo in a css class

Tags: php, html, css

I am using php echo throughout different pages on a project, to update a percentage value that is changing daily. This value can be negative or positive.

Here is my code:

```
<i class="icon-thumbs-up"><strong> <?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[n]; ?></strong></i>
```

I am using FontAwesome icons with a Bootstrap template. Everything is working fine like this.

Now, if the percentage is negative, I would like to use class="icon-thumbs-down" instead of class="icon-thumbs-up".

I have tried to achieve this using

```
<i class="<?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[n]; ?>"><strong> <?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[13]; ?></strong></i>
```

in order to change it on all pages.

However, this is not working. Thanks for any hints!

To clarify:

```
<i class="icon-thumbs-up"><strong> <?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[0]; ?></strong></i>
```

Content of include.text: 0.58% on line 1 -> All working fine. I got the thumbs up displayed and next to it the value 0.58%.

Now I tried to change to:

```
<i class="<?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[1]; ?>"><strong> <?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[0]; ?></strong></i>
```

Content of include.text: 0.58% on line 1 and icon-thumbs-up on line 2. (Which I would like to change in the include.txt on a daily basis to icon-thumbs-up or icon-thumbs-down, depending on the value of line 1.)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do hear. What is your code trying to do? In other words, what is expected output? Also, what is `include.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If value from `file('include.txt')` is integer then you can use ternary operator to echo correct css class, eg. like this:

```
<li class="<?php echo (int) $file[0] < 0 ? 'icon-thumbs-down' : 'icon-thumbs-up'; ?>"></li>
```

Comment: Not working. I tried it with -1 and 1, the thumb is always up. The other problem is that the values are like -0.75 or 1.66 - always with two decimals.

Comment: @MichaelHazelwood So they are floats not ints, use `(float)`. Also check value of `$file[0]` to be sure that everything is ok.

Comment: Using <i class="<?php echo (float) $file[13] < 0 ? 'icon-thumbs-down' : 'icon-thumbs-up'; ?>"><strong> <?php $file = file('include.txt');echo $file[13]; ?>%</strong></i> The percentage value is -0.63 and is displayed correctly in the second part. However the thumb is still up all the time, whatever value I am entering.

Comment: Found the problem :) There was no reference to the include.txt. Now I changed the code to class="<?php $file = file('include.txt');echo (float) $file[13] < 0 ? 'icon-thumbs-down' : 'icon-thumbs-up'; ?>" and everything is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to reply to as your code isnt that clear. I can however hand you the following suggestion via an example:

```
$someInt = 10;
echo $someInt < 0 ? 'icon-negative' : 'icon-positive'; // will echo positive

$someInt = -3;
echo $someInt < 0 ? 'icon-negative' : 'icon-positive'; // will echo negative
```

This is a short if/else (ternary). To demonstrate how it works, this would be the same in a full syntax:

```
$someInt = -3;
if($someInt < 0){
    echo 'icon-negative';
}
else{
    echo  'icon-positive'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
<?php
// your logic here, move in another file if this gets bigger:
function percentage($nb) {
  $file = file('include.txt');
  return $file[$nb];
}
?>
<i class="<?php echo percentage(5) > 0 ? 'positive' : 'negative' ?>">
  <strong>Text</strong>
</i>
```